# How to share a project with EAS like using expo publish

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, expo-go

I have build a small project and i want to share it with my friend that have both ios and android devices however the npx expo publish command doesnt work cause it has been deprecated. Is there any way to achieve this using the EAS ?I dont want to publish my app neither on App-Store nor on Play-Store